# Trying to return True if lists do NOT share elements, False otherwise. Minimum code

Tags: python

Hoping to get some assistance.  Trying to return True if they DON'T share any elements, False otherwise, while working on improving my "minimalist" coding (I can do this in multiple lines, but want to complete this in a line or two).

I am able to obtain True in single test, not able to get False in multiple test when written in different ways.  Here is what I have currently:

```
def different(listx, listy):

    return any(listx) == any(listy)
```

Suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: '0 == len(set(listx).intersection(set(listy)))`

Comment: `all(x not in listy for x in listx)`

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  I actually like this one best.  Simple for someone of my skill level, lol.  Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is cast each list to a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). From the docs a set is defined as:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

from there check if those sets are disjoint using the [`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) method.

```py
return set(listx).isdisjoint(set(listy))
```

Comment: I did it a longer way.  This is better.

Comment: Learned a new method now.  Very helpful.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

Set intersection:

```
print (0 == len(set(listx).intersection(set(listy))))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Perhaps not as performant as the other answers, but more readable in my opinion:*

**An expanded method, to help you see through the operations:**

```py
def different(listx, listy):
    """Will return True if lists don't have any common values."""
    n_shared = 0
    for x in listx:
        if x in listy:
            n_shared+=1
    if n_shared==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**A more minimal approach:**

```
def different(listx, listy):
    """Will return True if lists don't have any common values."""
    shared = [x for x in listx if x in listy]
    if len(shared)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```